# Why $t^5-5t^4+10t^3-8t^2+2t$ can't be a chromatic polynomial.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I'm trying to figure out why $p(t)=t^5-5t^4+10t^3-8t^2+2t$ can't be a chromatic polynomial.

Given that $p(2)=4>0$, the graph is 2-colorable. From the polynomial, the graph has 5 vertices and 4 edges. Here are the graphs I can come up with:
[image]
Have I covered all the possible cases? To show $p(t)$ can't be a chromatic polynomial, should I figure out the chromatic polynomial of each graph above and show none of them is $p(t)$? Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between your top two graphs at the right?

Comment: There is a catalog of graphs on 5 vertices [here](https://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes5), organized by edge count (from top to bottom, then left to right). It has six entries rather than five, but two of them contain triangles and therefore aren't 2-colorable. So minus the duplicate noted by David, that does seem to be the correct list.

Comment: Shouldn't there be 5 edges because the second highest coefficient is -5?

Comment: @Loreno Heer I'm a little confused if I should look at the power or the coefficient. For vertices I looked at the power.

Comment: It appears I misrepresented the catalog somewhat: the first column is ordered by edge count, but the second entry in the row is the graph complement. (Hence the graphs with 5 edges and 5 nodes are at the bottom of its section.)

Comment: The additional property you want is that the next-to-leading coefficient, aside from a minus sign, is the edge count. So the fact that it starts as $t^5-5t^4$ means that there are five edges over five vertices. (And, rather conveniently, only one of those graphs is bipartite.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $p(t)=t^5−5t^4+10t^3−8t^2+2t$
is a chromatic polynomial
then from the degree it follows $\deg(p)=5=n$ that there are $n=5$ vertices.
And from the coefficient $a_{n-1}=-5$ it follows that there must be $|-5| = 5$
edges. Checking the possible graphs there is only one which is 2 colorable: The $4$-pan graph with polynomial: $(x-1)^2+(x-1)^5=3 x - 9 x^2 + 10 x^3 - 5 x^4 + x^5$.